# android emulator on mac not showing alert box on deviceready

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i am new to phone gap with android emulator . using mac system

I am trying to show a pop up on device ready but that is not getting done . what am i doing wrong

my index.js is

```
    var app = {
        // Application Constructor
        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        // Bind Event Listeners
        //
        // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
        // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, true); 
// <== tried both true and false nothing happens 
        },
        // deviceready Event Handler
        //
        // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
        // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
        onDeviceReady: function() {

            alert("123");
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        },
        // Update DOM on a Received Event
        receivedEvent: function(id) {
            var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
            var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
            var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

            listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

            console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        }
    };
```

**EDIT**
As asked by people in comments , my Index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you have the `Notification` plugin installed and use `navigator.notification.alert("123")` instead of `alert("123")`

Comment: have you added `cordova.js` to you index.html file? can you show us your head tag of you index.html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs

cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git
```

This solved the problem .thanks all